# Why pagination provided by django rest framework is not consistent?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently using Django-Rest framework to implement the API endpoints. I am following the documentation to implement the pagination, my pagination class is,

```
class Pagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
    page_size_query_param = 'page'
```

I am using this class as follows:-

```
class QuestionList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Question.objects.all().prefetch_related('tags').order_by('id')
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    pagination_class = Pagination
```

For the first page, i am getting objects from id 1 to 10 which is expected. But from second page onwards, i am only getting 2 objects per page(id 3 and 4 for second page) and i cannot find any reason behind this strange behaviour.

What should i do to make the pagination consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I think `page_size_query_param = 'page'` is wrong. Is should be

```
page_size_query_param = 'size'
page_query_param = 'page'
```